# most comprehensive coverage of arithemetic and elementary algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, book-recommendation

To put it shortly, I never learned mathematics. I never learned the algorithms for multiplication and division, &c. (I had always just mentally scaled by powers of 10, making it unnecessary for me to ever learn algorithms for what was presented to me). I intend to remedy my lack of knowledge, and see how far I can go :) I wish for an abstract treatment of whatever I work on, or I will quickly become bored. (I'm a philosopher).

I wish to cover these topics first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_arithmetic

For elementary algebra, I discovered the book *Elements of Algebra* by Euler, but have the feeling that a more comprehensive and abstract treatment exists, as much of the book seems to focus on just finding the answer.

**I'm asking for recommendations on the most abstract and comprehensive coverage of arithmetic and elementary algebra. @_@**

Sorry to ask such a noobish thing, but I am of the opinion that there is almost always a near-optimal or optimal way to approach something, and this is no exception. I need to learn these things before I can go onto trigonometry, then analysis, &c.

Comment: Any book on elementary number theory will contain many in-depth uses of arithmetic.  Kenneth Rosen has a standard book that you can probably use.

Comment: @Joe, I went to look up the book you are recommending. From the reviews, it 'moves slowly', certainly not something I am looking for. Of course, reviews are not everything, but I'm looking for something with a bit more difficult/abstract reputation, as well as more connections to other things I will be studying in the very near future.